# Linear Programming constraint equivalent of conditional

Tags: integer-programming, constraints

I would like to use the following conditional in my linear program:

`if(A == 1) then B = C + 1`

A = binary, B and C are continuous. In the else case, any relation between B and C is possible.

Can someone help me?

I tried to use the method explained in: http://www.yzuda.org/Useful_Links/optimization/if-then-else-02.html but this doesn't seem to work with equalities, I think.

Comment: How about this one ? $$\cases{ B=C+1, \ \text{if} \ A=0 \\ \text{else}, \ \text{if} \ A \neq 0}$$ $A \in \{0,1\};B,C \in \mathbb R$

Comment: That's not a linear constraint?

Comment: Thats true. I think I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself.
As A is a binary, and B could be greater, the conditional becomes:

```
if(A>=1) then B>=C+1
```

Applying the method explained in the link I got these constraints:

```
A<=0+(1-y)
C+1 <= B + M*y
```

With y binary and M a large value.