# If-then-else condition to Linear Programming (equations) representation

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

```
if(P == 1) then T = A else T = 0;
```

Where P is binary, A is an int variable.
Basically `T = AP`

How to express this in linear equations?

I'm unable to figure out from [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234652/linear-programming-constraint-equivalent-of-conditional), [link2](http://www.yzuda.org/Useful_Links/optimization/if-then-else-01.html), [link3](http://www.yzuda.org/Useful_Links/optimization/if-then-else-02.html), [link4](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104717/if-then-condition-on-mixed-linear-integer-programming?newreg=39e5aa6f98d7478ab35c98d8dcd1b4d6), or [link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527088/if-statement-in-linear-programming).

Comment: You mean without using a binary variable ?

Comment: You can use binary variable, but equations should be linear. Here, all `P`, `T`, `A` are variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ell \le A \le u$ for constants $\ell$ and $u$, and impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
\ell (1-P) \le A - T &\le u (1-P) \tag1\\
\ell P \le T &\le u P \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $P=1 \implies T=A$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $P=0 \implies T = 0$.